# Dual boot Vista along with Debian

Tags: windows-vista, boot, debian, multi-boot

I'm a Windows user and have recently installed Debian 6 on my laptop. I installed it on a separate partition but for some reason after installing it I am unable to boot into Vista.

I'm new to Linux and don't know very much, any advice on what could have be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you overwrote Vista? If not, could you share some more information about the issue? Has GRUB taken over?

I feel this is a bootmanager issue

Comment: yep. I think grub has taken over. I didn't overwrite any file. Vista is still there but the problem is that it is not shown in the options while booting.

Comment: i wrote a comment. Please help.

Comment: Open console and type fdisk -l

Comment: Please post the feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

Open a console window

1. Backup your GRUB menu.lst

   sudo cp /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/menu.lst-backup
2. Edit your GRUB menu,lst

   sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
3. Add Vista to the list

   title Windows Vista

   root (hd0,0)

   makeactive

   chainloader +1

Once you post the results of the fdisk -l, I can tell you what to put in the 2nd line of step 3. hd0,0 is the first partition on your first harddrive.